# Where can packages such as the CVE'd apache2-bin=2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10 for Ubuntu 16.04 be installed from

Tags: 16.04, apt, server, upgrade, repository

I'm writing a script which uses the output of `apt list --installed` to install the same package version on a fresh VM install of (un-upgraded) 16.04.

The purpose is to test upgrade procedures, by creating a VM that is in the same "package-state" as a remote server (which suffers limited connectivity).

Some packages, such as `apache2-bin=2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10` are not installable because they are no longer in the main repos.

Where can discontinued packages be downloaded from?

Comment: Google, [package name] : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/apache2-bin/2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10 →  Downloadable files →  apache2-bin_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb

Comment: @KnudLarsen I found that, but they have an unguessable magic number in their URLs, so you'd need to scrap to automate... e.g. http://launchpadlibrarian.net/417551919/apache2-bin_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb

Comment: Typo: scrape, not scrap.

Comment: New link https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/16554854

Comment: @KnudLarsen That particular package can be found there, again with a magic-numbered link.  Adding ppa:ubuntu-security-proposed/ppa (and apt-get update) did not make it available to "apt-get install -y apache2-bin=2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10".  I'm looking for a general solution to discontinued packages - is that the right name for them?

Comment: Your question : »»  Where can discontinued packages be downloaded from? «« .... Packages from discontinued repo´s can be downloaded from [link], and then installed with `sudo gdebi Downloads/[package name]`. ( If you have or can download dependencies.)

Comment: @KnudLarsen, yes, you're right.  I've had to write a scraper to get .deb download URLs from several different sites, I should soon have a full set.